# AppleScript runs, but does not seem to work

Tags: applescript

I have an excel workbook open, with old file names in column A and new file names in column B. I am attempting to use the applescript below to rename my files. It runs without errors, but doesn't rename the files. Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

```
set theDirectory to "/Users/admin/Desktop/test/copied images"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        tell used range
            set rc to count of rows
        end tell
        set theList to get value of range ("A1:B" & rc) as list
        repeat with theItem in theList
            try
                do shell script "mv " & theDirectory & "/" & quoted form of item 1 of     theItem & space & theDirectory & "/" & quoted form of item 2 of theItem
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: There is a space in the path of `theDirectory`. You should apply `quoted form` to `theDirectory & "/" & item 1 of     theItem`. Likewise for the destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why your script seems to run without errors

Your script runs without errors because it swallows any error that may occur in the `do shell script` line.

Temporarily remove the surrounding `try` and `end try` lines to un-mute the errors. This will likely lead to an error message that ends with *No such file or directory.*

### Why your script does not rename files

The issue is that your script hands the value of `theDirectory` directly to the shell command without quoting it. Because that value contains spaces, the shell interprets the `directory &`[…]`theItem` part as two separate arguments, which causes `mv` to fail.

### Solution

In the `do shell script` line, replace both occurrences of

> `theDirectory`

with:

> `quoted form of theDirectory`

### (Optional) Making your script more robust

Additionally, I suggest that you either lose the surrounding `try`/`end try` altogether, or alternatively insert an `on error` statement to handle possible errors that can occur in the `do shell script` part.

Writing scripts that don’t swallow errors means you’ll save time in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this was really helpful. I now get an error - "the variable theDirectory is not defined"

Comment: had a sytax error i fixed in the first line. I now get an error I can't decypher - microsoft excel got an error: mv [-f] -i| -n] [-v] source target
mv [-f] -i| -n] [-v] source ... directory.

Comment: What does it say when you temporarily `log` your shell command line (instead of executing it with `do shell script`)?